# How do I setup routing through a PPTP VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, pptp

I have created a PPTP connection back to my office, and managed to setup routing as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3518/connecting-to-vpn-prevents-access-to-normal-web-sites/3536#3536), so that everything outside the office LAN keeps going to my current default gateway.

My problem is that I'd like to access some hosts in the office that are on a different subnet. Suppose I'm on the `1.2.x.y/24`subnet and through the VPN I can access the `192.168.2.x/24` subnet (the office LAN). I'd like to access the office DMZ at `192.168.0.x/24` through the VPN. How can I do that? (of course at the office the gateway on the LAN knows how to reach the DMZ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo route add 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.2.VPNENDPOINTADDRESS
```

the far end will either need to NAT or the far network will need to have a route back.

Comment: The obvious answer, means that if it's not working there's something wrong on the far end.