# Internet becomes unavailible after connecting through vpn

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn

I am connecting to vpnc which breaks my internet connection. I understand, that this is because all my traffic is forwarding to vpnc now, so the problem is about routing.

So, how can I manage my routes so only one port (1433) will use vpnc and all other connection won't pass traffic through vpn

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/3518/connecting-to-vpn-prevents-access-to-normal-web-sites

Comment: I can't access to vpnc settings through network manager (I have got just vpnc config file)

Comment: Linking [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225134/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-installing-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client) and [also this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264398/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client-broke-my-internet) for future Googlers. I found those answers to work for one of my machines and the one here to work for another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I have a solution. Please follow the procedure as mentioned below;

1. Open Network connection and click on VPN tab.
2. Click on VPN to be configured.
3. Now click on Edit
4. Go to IPV4/6 Settings
5. Click on Routes button
6. Now check the box in front of the text "Use the connections only for the resources on its network" (This will solve the problem of breakage of your internet connection)
7. Add a route using add button. (I am not expert in adding routes, so wont be able to help you out here. But this is the way, you would be able to add the routes).

Comment: Cool! But I can't access to vpnc settings through network manager (I have got just vpnc config file)

Comment: I have installed `network-manager-vpnc` so it works with Cisco VPN as well now. Thanx!

Comment: @Amey After step 6, I am able to happily browse internet after connecting to VPN. But then I am not able to access the internal resources! How to fix that?

Comment: step 7 wasn't necessary for me. I can access the my server in the VPN and browse the internet  in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

infact that with my vpn connection (ubuntu 10.04) i still could not connect to internet though i have already set "Use the connections only for the resources on its network" and "ignore auto obtain route...". This because network manager vpn alway add route 0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
when it connect. So i need to change default root again with add default gateway command:
sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
192.168.2.1 --> is gateway which i connect to internet.
And it's fine!

Comment: You can use MarkDown to format your answer.