# No internet after VPN software

Tags: internet, vpn

So this has been bugging me for a few days now.

I tried connecting through a softlayer vpn. Their website ran a java applet and I noticed now that I can only connect at work through the one wifi connection at work. All other wifi connections or ethernet cable shows that everything is connected, but I'm unable to ping anything. I feel dumb but I don't know how to debug this. Any help much appreciated. This has been frustraing.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution

[Cannot connect to the internet after installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225134/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-installing-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client)

sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf