# How to fix name resolution issue after an update to Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client on an Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn, cisco, resolvconf, rdesktop

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and used to connect to a remote desktop using the following command line:

```
rdesktop -u username -g 90% MachineName.DepartmentName.StateName.edu
```

of course after connecting through Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.

However, yesterday *Cisco* package was updated and then suddenly the following error message is displayed after running the above command line:

> ERROR: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution

This page ([Cannot connect to the internet after installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225134/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-installing-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client)) says that resolve.conf should be restored to its original version. Running the following code does not resolve the issue as it is suggested in the page:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/228615/692175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to the internet after installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225134/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-installing-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client)

Comment: @MichaelBay. I am afraid of running *sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf* as I am not sure what it exactly does. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: It restores the original version.

Comment: Did it. No success. The same issue with the same error message.

Comment: Perhaps you need to contact Cisco, report a bug or something...

Comment: This question is not similar to the one posted earlier. I contacted Cisco but it seems they are not concerned with people's issues and never got back to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" window, where it says "connect to" in the first line, there was an extra space in the link provided and after few months, I just figured that out after speculating that some file (which I still do not know what) should have been corrupted due to a wrong URL entry. By trying entering the same link to the vpn address by **typing** it literally rather than copying and pasting,it turned out that only an invisible empty at the end was the cause of the problem.