# Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client broke my internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I was using the AnyConnect client when it froze and I had to do a hard reboot of my computer. Now I can't connect to the internet at all, with or without VPN. The Network Connections manager seems to think I have a wired and wireless connection without a problem, but I can't go online.

I have tried using `/etc/init.d/networking restart` and it even says it is "ok" with no luck.

I am guessing I need to clear some settings somewhere and restart a service, but I am not sure what. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This Cisco stuff changes your `/etc/resolv.conf`. 
I have to manually remove the DNS entries it configures every time I have to use it. It just leaves without resetting anything on stop.

Make sure your `/etc/resolv.conf` just contains one line like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```