# After connecting VPN my internet stops working on ubuntu system

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** on my desktop, my internet is on wifi via d-link dongle.

Before VPN connection inter is working fine with good speed. But once I connect VPN internet is not available on Ubuntu system, also the gateway which is router IP is not pingable.

I found this below link but I am connecting via **forticlient VPN**, but the steps are not applicable for me.

[Internet becomes unavailible after connecting through vpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84344/internet-becomes-unavailible-after-connecting-through-vpn)

Step 1 & 2 are not applicable for me.
[image]

But I have done step 4 & 5 which on WIFI Network, but still not working.
[image]

Comment: How are you connecting to the VPN? From the command line or via Network Manager? If from the command line, what command do you use?

Comment: Further question: Do you have a firewall running (ufw, iptables)?

Comment: @Sebastian I am connection VPN via forticlient. & Yes firewall is disabled, if it was not disabled then it would have not be working when the VPN is disconnected.

Comment: I don't know what "forticlient" is, but it may mess with your network settings. You might add the outputs of `ifconfig` and `route` before and after connecting the VPN, it may help tracking down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 20.04 too with FortiClient VPN. I found that **NetworkManager** handle these configurations relate to network.

You can try **nm-connection-editor** then **Select your default network**, select **General tab** and check if **Connect automatically with priority**: **Enable** with positive value (>0). My value was -999 then I changed to 100. Network work again. Although I didn't find root problem yet.